# Vim: what variables can I use in printheader?

Tags: vim

I checked http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/print.html, which says printheader is `%<%f%h%m%=Page %N` by default.

But how to read `%<%f%h%m%=Page %N` ? What are the meaning of the variables? Is there a full list of variables that we can put in the header?

Links to Vim documentation are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you have to make two jumps, the information is then at `:help 'statusline'`.

The format is `%-0{minwid}.{maxwid}{item}`, usually just `%` + another character.

Note that when you change it, spaces have to be escaped with `\`:

```
:set printheader=%<%f%h%m%=Page\ %N
```

or you use `:let`:

```
:let &printheader = '%<%f%h%m%=Page %N'
```